# Time-limit for block in Qualtrics

Tags: javascript, timer, block, timing, qualtrics

I need to set a time limit for an entire block in Qualtrics. The survey consists of 5 blocks, and I want block 4 to have a 10 minute long time limit. Qualtrics provides this feature for each page, but I don't know how I should code the JavaScript for this purpose.

I already appreciate your help.

P.S.

Before the block I defined embedded data "sb1" as:

```
${e://Field/Q_TotalDuration}
```

Then for every page of the block I'm adding the following to the JavaScript:

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function()
{
var elapsed = parseInt("${e://Field/Q_TotalDuration}") - parseInt("${e://Field/sb1}");
if(elapsed >= 600) {
$('NextButton').click();
}
});
```

But unfortunately it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

The immediate problem is that you need to defer the execution of $('NextButton').click() in JFE. It is a timing issue...the NextButton isn't there when your code executes.

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function() {
  var elapsed = parseInt("${e://Field/Q_TotalDuration}") -  parseInt("${e://Field/sb1}");
  if(elapsed >= 600) {
    clickId.defer('NextButton');
  }

  function clickId(id) {
    $(id).click();
  }
});
```

Another potential problem is that your script only executes when the page loads. It's not clear that is what you want.  If not, you need to add a JavaScript setInterval or prototypejs PeriodicalExecuter function to increment the elapsed variable and click Next when the time limit is reached. If you take this approach you can't force response or validate any of the questions.